# How to find a specific value in a nested array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array, indexing

I'm trying to figure out how to place a value into one of three arrays and then shuffle those arrays and have the program output the index location of the value.

Here is what I have so far:

```
# The purpose of this program is to randomly place the name Zac
# in one of three arrays and return the array number and position of
# Zac

A1 = ["John","Steve","Frank","Charles"]
A2 = ["Sam","Clint","Stuart","James"]
A3 = ["Vic","Jim","Bill","David"]

n = [A1,A2,A3]

name = "Zac"

def placename(title, namelist)
  mix = rand(2)
  namelist[mix] << title
  namelist.shuffle
  return namelist
end

allnames = [] << placename(name, n)

def findname(allnames, key)
  allnames.each do |i|
    until allnames[i].include?(key) == true
      i+=1
    end
      location = allnames[i].find_index(key)
      puts "The location and value of #{key} is #{location}"
  end
end

findname(allnames, name)
```

At the moment I'm getting a "undefined method for Nil Class" error (no method error)

Can someone please clarify what I'm doing wrong with this or if there is a more effective way of going about this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Tip: Don't bother declaring the intermediate arrays, just go at this one-shot, like `NAMES = [ [ "John", ... ], [ ... ] ]`.

Comment: `placename` is really just `n.sample << title`. That's so trivial it doesn't even need a function.

Comment: Tadman- I appreciate the tip! In this instance I was actually just trying to learn "how" to access the index number for a specified value from within a multidimensional array. Just for my own knowledge. That was really the part I was intending to focus on with this piece. Thank you for your help!! The placename point makes sense as well so thanks for that.

Comment: The error message tells you a) what the name of the method is you are trying to call, b) what method the call occurs in, c) what file the error occurs in, d) what line that error occurs in. It tells you everything you need to locate the error. The stack trace tells you *how you got* to that point where the error occurred. Since you are the only one who has this information, you are the only one who can really solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the last fewlines. I hope this is what you wanted

```rb
allnames = placename(name, n)
def findname allnames, key
    r = allnames.map.with_index{|x,i|x.include?(key) ? i : p}-[p]
    puts "The location of value #{key} is array number #{r[0]} and item number #{allnames[r[0]].index(key)}"
end

findname(allnames, name)
```

Edit: Randomization

To get randomized array number and item number you have to do the following

```rb
def placename(title, namelist)
  mix = rand(3)  # Since the number of arrays (nested within) is 3 we can use 3 instead of 2
  namelist[mix] << title
  namelist.map!{|x|x.shuffle}.shuffle!  # Shuffling each item and the whole array in place.
  return namelist
end
```

Comment: Hey John - I noticed this program outputs the same array number and item number each time though. The program should be shuffling the value "Zac" and placing it into a different array and item number each time it executes. Can you explain what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach assumes that in the block starting...

```
allnames.each do |i|
```

... that `i` will contain the index of the allnames element.  This isn't true. `i` will contain the VALUE (contents) of the element.

What you could try as an alternative is...

```
allnames.each_with_index do |_value, i|
```

or, you can do...

```
allnames.each do |value|
```

and then replace all references to `allnames[i]` with `value`

another problem is that...

```
allnames = [] << placename(name, n)
```

puts the returned array of arrays inside ANOTHER array.  I think what you want to do is..

```
allnames = placename(name, n)
```

Comment: Steve - thanks for the tip on the ```allnames = placename(name, n)``` I was wondering why it was nested twice!! Could you tell me why you have two values in the block for ```allnames.each_with_index do |value, i|``` ? I just want to understand is that going to store the value of the element in the first variable (_value) and store the index number in the second (i)? or how does that work?

Comment: yes exactly, `each` teturns the value, `each_with_index` returns the value and the index. Since you don't actually reference the value  the convention is to precede the variable name with an underscore `_value` Alternatively, you could go back to `each`... I'll update my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to modify the array in place, I'd do it like this:

```
# insert name into random subarray
def insert_name name
  subarray_idx  = rand @name_arrays.size
  subarray      = @name_arrays[subarray_idx]
  insertion_idx = rand subarray.size
  @name_arrays[subarray_idx].insert insertion_idx, name
  sprintf '"%s" inserted at @name_arrays[%d][%d]',
    name, subarray_idx, insertion_idx
end

# define starting array, then print & return the
# message for further parsing if needed
@name_arrays = [
  %w[John Steve Frank Charles],
  %w[Sam Clint Stuart James],
  %w[Vic Jim Bill David],
]
p(insert_name 'Zac')
```

This has a few benefits:

1. You can inspect *@name_arrays* to validate that things look the way you expect.
2. The message can be parsed with [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/String.html#method-i-scan) if desired.
3. You can modify #insert_name to return your indexes, rather than having to search for the name directly.

If you don't capture the insertion index as a return value, or don't want to parse it from your message String, you can search for it by leveraging [Enumerable#each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) and [Array#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-index). For example:

```rb
# for demonstration only, set this so you can get the same
# results since the insertion index was randomized
@name_arrays = 
  [["John", "Steve", "Frank", "Charles"],
   ["Sam", "Clint", "Stuart", "James"],
   ["Vic", "Jim", "Zac", "Bill", "David"]]

# return indices of nested match
def find_name_idx name
  @name_arrays.each_with_index
    .map { [_2, _1.index(name)] }
    .reject { _1.any? nil }
    .pop
end

# use Array#dig to retrieve item at nested index
@name_arrays.dig *find_name_idx('Zac')
```

Comment: This answer is a bit out of my experience level. I'll have to refer to this a little later down the road so it makes more sense.